# Can't change Opportunity owner from Trigger because Error record is 'read-only'

Tags: trigger, opportunity, account, read-only

This is supposed to be a simple trigger that changes the Opportunity Owner to the the Account Owner upon insert or update of the opportunity. However, I keep getting the error, cannot update the Opportunity because the record is read only.

How should I modify this?

```
trigger ChangeOwner on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {
 for(Opportunity op : Trigger.New) {

   Account account = [SELECT OwnerId FROM Account Where Id = :op.AccountId];

   op.OwnerId = account.OwnerId;

   update op;   
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, let me say that your trigger isn't "bulkified". You're running a query for each opp.

The first thing you need to do is create a map of oppIds to Acct IDs and collect a set containing all the AcctId's in trigger.new (opp.account).

After that, run your query to get a list of OwnerId's for the Accounts .

**Then** run your for loop where you test to see if the OwnerID matches the Account OwnerID. If it doesn't, then assign it to the the opp.OwnerID. After exiting the for loop, if your list isn't empty, then do an update. Here's some pseudo code for the last part:

```
set<ID>accts = new set<Id>();
map<ID,ID>op2acct = new map<Id,Id>();

for{
 collect acct ID's and create the map
}

map<Account> acctmap = new map([SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Account Where Id IN :accts]);
list<Opportunity>ToUpdate = new list<Opportunity>();

for(Opportunity op trigger.new){

   if(op.OwnerID != acctmap.get(op2acct.get(op.Id)){
      // you only want to assign a new value if its different. 
      //If this were an after update and not also after insert, you could use trigger.oldmap as part of the compare criteria to simplify it 

      op.OwnerID = acctmap.get(op2acct.get(op.Id)); 

      ToUpdate.add(op);

   }
}

If(ToUpdate.isEmpty() == false) Update toUpdate;
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is saying the record is read only is because your trigger is firing in an after context. The record is read only in this context. I would recommend changing it to a before trigger and then doing the Owner update. You only need to do the field assignment, it will be inserted correctly because the insert happens after the trigger fires.

I also agree with crmprogdev that your trigger is not bulk and you'll run into a problem anytime multiple opportunities get updated at the same time.

Comment: For the sake of clarity, it's `trigger.new` that's read only which is what he's trying to update in his trigger as its currently written. Once he moves the update to outside of `trigger.new`, he can perform the update to those records in an after trigger.

Comment: @crmprogdev: That's true, but then you will have to deal with an infinite loop of Opportunity triggers as well. In this use case, I would always recommend a before trigger for the simplicity of modifying a triggering record.

Comment: That's why I wrote the above to only update the OwnerID by checking first to see if it was necessary. That avoids the infinite loop. But I do understand & get your point.